# what is the right way or the vuejs way to data bind the entire page?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Coming from the knockoutJs background. If you don't specific the binding to an element. You can use the model to cover the whole page of elements. For example, i can make a div visible if a click event happened. I'm learning VueJs and from the documentation. I see the vue instance required you to speicif an element with el.

like this:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

what if my button is not in the same div as the '#app' div. How do i communicate between two vue instance or can I use one vue instance to cover more than one element. what's the vuejs way?

Comment: Usually the `#app` would be a direct child of the `body` and wrap all other elements (other than e.g. `script` tags).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very common to bind to the first element inside `<body>`. Vue won't let you bind to `body`, because there are all sorts of other things that put their event listeners on it.

If you do that, Vue is managing your whole page, and away you go. The docs cover the case where you have more than one Vue instance on a page, but I haven't come across this outside the docs, and I can't think of a good reason off the top of my head. More commonly, you will be constantly chopping bits out of your root Vue instance and refactoring them into "child" components. This is how you keep file sizes manageable and structure your app.

This is where a lot of folk needlessly complicate things, by over-using `props` to pass stuff to components. When you start refactoring into components, you will have a much easier time if you keep all your state in a store, outside vue, then have your components talk directly to your store. (put the store in the `data` element of all components). This pattern (MVVM) is fabulous, because many elements of state will end up having more than one representation on screen, and having a "single source of truth", normalized, with minimal relationships between items in the store, radically reduces the complexity and the amount of code for most common purposes. It lets you structure your app state independently of your DOM.

So, to answer your question, Vue instances (and vue components), don't need to (and shouldn't) talk much to each other. When they do need to (third party components and repeated components), you have [props and events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components), [refs and method calls](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) (state outside the store), and the [$parent and $root](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-parent) properties (usage frowned on!). You can also create [an event bus](https://medium.com/patrickleenyc/vue-js-simple-event-bus-for-cross-component-communication-85dd8f0fc750). [This page](https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-communication/) is a really good summary of the options.

Should your store be Flux/Redux? Vuex is the official implementation of the flux/redux pattern for vue. The common joke goes: when you realize you need it, it's too late. If you do decide to leave Vuex for now, don't just put state in Vue components. Use a plain javascript object in window scope. The right way is easier than the wrong way, and when you do transition to Vuex, your job will be much simpler. Your downstream references might be alright as they are.

Good luck. Enjoy the ride.

Answer (score 1):

You usually put the main Vue instance on the first tag inside the body, then build the rest of your site within it. Everything directly inside that instance (not in a nested component) will have access to the same `data`.

You can then do this in your HTML:

```html
<body>
  <div id="#app">
    <p v-if="showMessage">{{message}}</p>
    <button v-on:click="showMessage = !showMessage"></button>
  </div>
</body>
```

And set your data to something like this:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!',
    showMessage: true
  }
})
```

If you want to pass data between components later on you'll have to look up how to emit events, use props, or possibly use Vuex if you got Vue running with the Vue-CLI (which I highly recommend).

If you want to reach tags (such as head tags) outside of the main Vue instance, then there are tools for that. For example you could try: https://github.com/ktquez/vue-head

I haven't tested it thought.